# Calling package's procedure from another procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, package

Trying to search but i couldn't find it.

I have a package name `package_1` and in that I have multiple procedures/functions. Now I want to call one of these functions from another procedure, which is not part of this package. I can't put this code in that package (both are on same schema).

I am trying this

`package_1.function_1(varchar_var_1, varchar_var_2, varchar_var_3);`

But it is giving me error.

**QUESTION2**
The above functions return an object which is a record type defined in package. How can I declare an object of that type in my procedure so that I can assign response in my procedure ?

Comment: Oh, I fixed it :) ... I was calling a function and for testing I hadn't assigned its return value to anything and Oracle was thinking i am trying to call a procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function returns a record type, you'd need to declare a local variable in the caller of that record type.  Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE your_procedure_name( <<parameters>> )
AS
  l_rec package_1.record_type;
  ...
BEGIN
  ...
  l_rec := package_1.function_name( p1, p2, p3 );
  ...
END;
```

Of course, this assumes that both the record type and the function are defined in the package spec so that they are public rather than merely being defined as private members of the package that are defined only in the package body.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if it is declared in the package header/specification. If it is you
   will have access to it.
2. Function must return a value:

   a_value := package_1.function_1(varchar_var_1, varchar_var_2, varchar_var_3);
3. Check if the package is valid. If it is invalidated then there is not
   much you can do (until it is fixed).